# Regular Surface and Smooth Surface

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm a beginner in Differential Geometry and I'm confused by the terminologies. In do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*, a 'regular surface' is a set that is defined locally by a smooth homeomorphism and its differential (page 52 in do Carmo's, ). However, I also read the *Elementary Differential Geometry* by Pressley, in which the concept of a 'smooth surface' is proposed (page 77 in Pressley's). The definition of a smooth surface is very similar to the regular surface in do Carmo's. I think two definitions in these two books are essentially the same. Am I right?

Definition from do Carmo's: A regular surface is a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. for each $p \in S$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $ S$, open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a map $X$ from $U$ to $V \cap S$:

1. $X$ is differentiable.
2. $X$ a homeomorphism in terms of the neighborhoods.
3. $\forall q \in U$, the differential of $X$ at $q$ is injective.

Definition from Pressley's: It firstly define what is a surface by defining a subset of $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with property 2 in do Carmo's. The homeomorphism is called a **surface patch**. Then comes the definition of **regular surface patch** as maps that are smooth and satisfy property 3 in do Carmo's. Finally, a **smooth surface** is defined by: $\forall p \in S$, we can locally find such regular surface patch locally in a neighborhood of p.

Comment: Probably, yes, but I'd need the definitions. In general, what is a "surface" in your setting depends on what you want to do, and it boils down to the regularity of transition maps between charts. Do you want them to be smooth? You have a smooth surface. $C^1$? You have a $C^1 $ surface. You just want to do topology? Then a chart just needs to be an homeomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^n$. You just want to integrate differential forms on it? Then you can define the dual of differential forms (called "currents") and you can find out that smooth manifolds are a subset of these "generalised" manifolds.

Comment: Anyway, to be 100% sure I'd need the precise definitions. I think that there's only one way to be a smooth manifold, maybe with different definitions, but equivalent

Comment: @tommy1996q Thanks for your response. Since the definitions are very tedious and long so I only gave the page numbers where the definitions are located. Will add those definitions later if I had time.

Comment: No problem, but personally I don't have access tot he texts right now, so I can't really help you without them. Again, I bet they're equaivalent, but who knows

Comment: @tommy1996q Yes, thank you. I have typed the definitions below as my answer. Basically those are the definitions, and I omitted some very detailed sentences in Pressley's. Please see if I were correct.

Comment: I typed the definitions correspondingly, in my own language. Hopefully my typings are correct...

Comment: OK, so as I asked earlier: Go through step by step. Does 1. appear in Pressley? Does 2? Does 3? Is there any hypothesis in Pressley that is missing in DoCarmo?

Comment: By the way, @tommy1996q, you're way off the deep end, thinking about abstract manifolds. These are all surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$. No chart overlaps.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot! After thinking for a while I personally think all 3 appears in Pressley, and I think the definitions are the same. The only difference is that Pressley gives more intermediate definitions and moves forward one definition per step, and finally comes to 'smooth surface'. But do Carmo gives all 3 properties at the same time to define a 'regular surface'.

Comment: Yeah I was about to delete my comment, but maybe I'll give a little bit of context here: @Stack_Underflow the factis that you can give a differential structure to "any" set, even if it doesn't have any geometrical meaning or is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. These are "abstract manifolds". But your situation is much simpler, and you don't have to worry about this. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Stack_Underflow Yes, you're right. Pressley establishes a little bit more vocabulary. In general, you'll find that Pressley gives a more immediately digestible treatment of the material than DoCarmo. For a third competitor, you might download my free text, linked in my profile. :P

Comment: Anyhow, see if you can write up a concise but complete answer to your own question now. (You can undelete your previous one and edit it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have visited your webpage and saw your book before this comment :). Really a good one and I'll make it one of my reference. Also, I have edited my previous post. @TedShifrin

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @tommy1996q

Answer (score 1):

Definition from do Carmo's: A regular surface is a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. for each $p \in S$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $ S$, open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a map $X$ from $U$ to $V \cap S$:

1. $X$ is differentiable.
2. $X$ a homeomorphism in terms of the neighborhoods.
3. $\forall q \in U$, the differential of $X$ at $q$ is injective.

Definition from Pressley's: It firstly define what is a surface by defining a subset of $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with property 2 in do Carmo's. The homeomorphism is called a **surface patch**. Then comes the definition of **regular surface patch** as maps that are smooth and satisfy property 3 in do Carmo's. Finally, a **smooth surface** is defined by: $\forall p \in S$, we can locally find such regular surface patch locally in a neighborhood of p.

Latest Edit: Thanks for the answers and instructions given by Ted Shifrin and Tommy1996q. I undeleted and edited this post. The definitions mentioned above are equivalent.

To wit, given a 'smooth surface' $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, we verify that it is a 'regular surface': Take $p \in S$, we can find a 'regular surface patch', which is a differentiable homeomorphism $X : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $p \in X(U)$. Since homeomorphism carries open to open, then this condition immediately gives properties 1 and 2 in do Carmo's. Since $X$ is a 'regular surface patch', its Jacobian has rank 2, which satisfies condition3 in do Carmo's.

Another way around, given a 'regular surface' $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, $\forall p \in S$, we can find some neighborhoods and a differentiable homeomorphism $X$. Not hard to verify the $X$ is the regular surface patch (More precisely, allowable surface patch). Therefore $S$ is a 'smooth surface'.

Comment: I typed the definitions correspondingly, in my own language. Hopefully my typings are correct...

Comment: @TedShifrin Got it, will delete this one.